# PHP - Unir array com array multidirecional PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Como fazer para unir arrays com um array multidimensional:

```php
Array (
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 3 
        [3] => 4 
        [4] => 5 
        [5] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 1 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 2 ) 
        [7] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 3 ) 
        [8] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 5 ) 
)
```

Veja como esta meu código:

```
//$item_inventarios = valor recebido da controller codeigniter  

$inicial = $listar_menor_maior_setor[0]['menor_cod_setor'];
$final = $listar_menor_maior_setor[0]['maior_cod_setor'];

$lista = range($inicial, $final);
$total = array_merge($lista,$item_inventarios);

print_r($total);
```

O resultado esperado seria este:

```
Array (
        [0] => Array ( [ambiente_setor] => 1 )
        [1] => Array ( [ambiente_setor] => 2 )
        [2] => Array ( [ambiente_setor] => 3 )
        [3] => Array ( [ambiente_setor] => 4 )
        [4] => Array ( [ambiente_setor] => 5 )
        [5] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 1 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 2 ) 
        [7] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 3 ) 
        [8] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 5 ) 
)
```

Comment: Que tipo de união seria essa? Qual seria o resultado esperado?

Comment: O resultado esperado seria este:

`Array (
        [0] => Array ( [ambiente_setor] => 1 )
        [1] => Array ( [ambiente_setor] => 2 )
        [2] => Array ( [ambiente_setor] => 3 )
        [3] => Array ( [ambiente_setor] => 4 )
        [4] => Array ( [ambiente_setor] => 5 )
        [5] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 1 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 2 ) 
        [7] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 3 ) 
        [8] => Array ( [cod_setor] => 5 ) 
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem várias operações possíveis com o arrays, diversas.

Por exemplo você pode usar o operador `+` para fazer isso, exemplo:

```
$array = [1,2,4];
$array_b = [5,6,7];
$array_sum = $array + $array_b;
print_r($array_sum); // [1,2,4,5,6,7]
```

Outra forma é através da função `array_map`:

```
$array_sum = array_map(function () {
   return array_sum(func_get_args());
 }, $array_a, $array_b);

 print_r($array_sum);
```

Voce também pode usar veridic functions:

```
$array_sum = array_map(function (...$arrays) {
    return array_sum($arrays);
}, $a, $b);

print_r($array_sum);
```

Somar dois arrays não se trata de framework, e sim lógica, mas basciamente é isso, agora é só pegar o contexto e aplicar na sua aplicação e lógica.

Para mais e duvidas sobre como funciona arrays **sempre olhe a documentação antes**, pois a documentação principalmente em inglês está cheia de referencias que possa ser uteis para voce e dicar e problemas em relação a sua duvida (principalmente a parte de arrays).

Comment: Obrigado por sua opinião.
A duvida não é somar somar dois arrays. ..Preciso unir dos arrays sendo que um deles é arrays multidimecional.

Nenhum os exemplos acima traria o resultado desejado.

Comment: O termo correcto seria concatena-los, para isso você pode usar o `array_merge` ou `array_merge_recursive`, tem também o `array_replace_recursive`, os 3 resolvem seu problema de maneiras diferentes. Eu acredito que o `array_merge_recursive` será o suficiente para o seu caso, mas novamente, oriento que dê uma olhada na documentação para verificar como as funções vai resolver o seu problema dentro do contexto da sua aplicação.

Comment: Posso tá errando, mas tanto `array_merge` quanto `array_merge_recursive` apenas concatena os arrays. 

No meu caso tenho um array criado dinamicamente com a função `range` que cria o array com valores de 1 a 5 e as chaves são geradas na sequencia também. queria que essas chaves fossem geradas com uma string com um valor único para todas as chaves do array.

Comment: Bem, entendi, talvez seja necessário voce manipular algumas coisas no seu array antes de reindexa-los, aqui tem uns exercicios sobre arrays e eu acho que a lógica por trás desse poderá te ajudar -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-sum-two-elements-two-arrays-indexes-not/

Comment: Perfeito. Acabei mudando a logica do meu sistema para para tratar esses dados de um outra forma.

Comment: Olá, mas voce pode marcar qual é a resposta certa por favor? Assim ajudará outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.